# Issue getting footer to "stick" to the bottom of the page

Tags: css, stylesheet

I am having an issue with a worpress template, I am trying to get the footer to stick to the bottom of the page.  I have found code to do this but on some pages there is a grey section between the footer and the body of the content.  I have inspected this in firebug bug there seems to be nothing there.  It only happens on screen with high resolution eg 1280x1024 but it is fine on my laptop which has more of a widescreen resolution (1280x800)

Here is the link one of the offending pages: http://caroline.ie/yourbrownenvelope/?page_id=74

Any ideas what could be causing this grey bar?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#wrapper {
height:auto !important;
margin:0 auto -74px;
min-height:100%;
}
```

You will have to change your wrapper structure abit. The negative margin and min-height seems to cause this weird behaviour.

Check out this link http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ for a solid sticky footer solution.

Comment: I tried those suggestions and now the footer isn't sticky at all, it appears straight below the text.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong, in fact I just dont understand enough about what I am trying to do.  When I hover over the wrapper in firebug not it is not being picked up and highlighted in blue.

Comment: That's because you are using an outline div. You have to edit the selectors in a way so that they fit your structure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would love a more specific solution.  I cannot remove the outline, tried that and it messes up the layout of the page, I don't know enough about what the css is trying to do in order to be able to just add the css where it is appropriate - hence asking the question.  I had already tried the sticky footer you suggested before I posted but it didn't work, that's why I tried a different one.  If you could provide me with more specific help I would really appreciate it.  Thanks in advance

Comment: managed to fix it, when I changed outline to wrapper and got rid of the original wrapper it became sticky but took up the whole width of the screen instead of just the center part.  margin 0 auto and a width fixed it!  Thanks for the help, glad it is finally sorted